# DB2/400 - Create new summary table based on joining header and detail tables

Tags: sql, db2-400

I want to Create new summary table based on joining Order header and detail tables.
I am working with this code so far (not yet working). I suspect I have to define data type for MIN fields.

```
CREATE TABLE SUMMARY AS (

SELECT  ORDHED.ORDERNO, ORDHED.CUSTNO,
  COUNT(ORDHED.LINENO) AS LINECNT,  
  MIN((CCSTCN*1000000)+(CCSTYR*10000)+(CCSTMO*100)+CCSTDA) AS ORD_DATE,
  MIN(ORDDET.CURRRENCY) AS CURRENCY

FROM ORDHED JOIN ORDDET
  ON (ORDHED.ORDERNO= ORDDET.ORDERNO )
  GROUP BY ORDHED.ORDERNO, ORDHED.CUSTNO
  ORDER BY ORDHED.ORDERNO, ORDHED.CUSTNO
)
WITH DATA;
```

Simplified version, as original is 3 pages long.

Comment: You don't need types.  You need names.

Comment: added. Should it work now?

Comment: Error:: [SQL0206] Column or global variable CURRRENCYnot found. Cause . . . . . :   CURRRENCYwas not found as a column of table *N in *N and was not found as a...
(Same with other variables).

Would it be better done as subselect?